# ITEXT and PDFBOX is not detecting all the form fields present in the pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, itext7

In this code I've used for finding the number of fields in the pdf using `Itext` and `PDFBOX` with Java, I'm attaching the pdf, it has 11 fields but the fields present in the page 1 are not getting detected and the size being printed is 2 for the cases.

```
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(doc, true);
        System.out.println("form fields size from Itext:"+form.getFormFields().size());


        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();
        System.out.println("form fields size from PDFBOX:"+fields.size());
```

[PDF FILE HERE IN THIS LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_h1mDVI2kPnhiD-s1XhBzCJG-ZJiQ-V/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form information in your PDF is inconsistent.

The global **AcroForm** form definition in your PDF contains only 2 fields, `Text Field 6` and `Text Field 7`, which happen to be the two fields on page two.

Page one in its **Annots** array references ten form field widgets, each of them merged with a form field object. These fields are not referenced from the **AcroForm** form definition in your PDF. Thus, they are not part of the form of the PDF but merely some arbitrary annotations hanging around.

To fix the issue, simply reference the form fields of the widget annotations of page one from the **AcroForm** form definition.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, can you help me with providing the code part on how to reference the form fields of widget annotations from acroform form definition.

Comment: @AkhilNagaSai I would say the question is not for code how to fix or circumvent the PDF problem. The PDF itself should be fixed (by the creator) - by the one who incorrectly added the form fields. Because then you can correctly retrieve all form fields...

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lonzak . Shall take care

Comment: @AkhilNagaSai As Lonzak said, the creator of the source PDF should fix it before distributing it. If you are in a position, though, in which you cannot make the creator of the PDF fix it but have to use the PDF as it is, you indeed can use iText, OpenPDF, or PDFBox to fix it. If you need help with that, please create a new question focusing on that task.